# Will inverse functions, and functions always meet at the line $y=x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inverse

If I have a function, the inverse function, by definition will be a reflection of the original function in the line $y=x$, so if I wanted to find the point of intersection, instead of solving it with equating both of the functions to equaling each other, could I assume that the point of intersection, between the two functions, will always be at the point $y=x$?

This would enable me to solve problems much easier, instead of having to solve quartic equations, for example.

Comment: When you meant "intersection", you mean the intersection of the image sets of the function and its inverse?

Comment: @marra, yes, that is correct.

Comment: Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},x\mapsto x+1$. So $y=x+1\iff x=y-1$ and $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},x\mapsto x-1$ is the inverse function. To look for an intersection point has to hold that $x-1=x+1$ which is clearly false. So here you have two functions, one being the inverse of the other which they do not intersect

Comment: Then the proposition is in general false. Consider, for instance the functions $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x-1$. They are the inverse one of the other and their image sets don't have an intersection

Comment: @sky90 we thought of the very same example :-P

Comment: @sky90, the question is proposed to those functions, which do intersect, at a point.

Comment: @Marra this is funny ^^

Comment: For example, f(X) = x^2-6

Comment: @Gurjinder this function you gave is not invertible in general. Not that simply reflecting a function over the $y=x$ line is not a general way of finding its inverse, since it can't even exist.

Comment: Sorry, for the range of the function being X>0.

Comment: I think an example might help: for example if on the non-negative reals $y=4x^2$, then the inverse function would be $y=\frac12\sqrt{x}$.  You seem to be asking whether instead of solving $4x^2=\frac12\sqrt{x}$ or $16x^4=\frac14 x$ you can just solve $4x^2 = x$.

Comment: @Henry, yes sorry

Comment: The title question's answer is No: $f(x)=-1/x$ meets its inverse (which happens to be itself) at infinitely many points, none of which occur on the $y=x$ line. My fuller explanation (and proof of the corrected proposition) is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4440456/21813).

Answer (score 18):

Not necessarily. If $f(x)=-x$, this implies that $f^{-1}(x)=-x$, (since $f(f(x))=f(-x)=x$), so the graphs of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ intersect everywhere.

Another example is $g(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$, which is also its own inverse, but doesn't intersect $y=x$ at all.

Comment: Oh, okay, cheers.

Answer (score 16):

As already pointed out by [sky90](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/77885/sky90) and [Marra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27071/marra) in the comments, in general a function and its inverse do not need to have an intersection. This can be seen from the example given in the comments. Another example would be $f(x)=\exp(x)$ and its inverse $f^{-1}(x) = \log(x)$, whose graphs never intersect.

Note that apart from the case mentioned by [Chappers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221811/chappers), where a function is its own inverse and there is an infinite number of intersections, you can also find examples with a finite set of intersections, e.g. $f(x) = -x^3$ and its inverse $f^{-1}(x) = -\sqrt[3]{x}$, whose graphs intersect at the points $(-1,1)$, $(0,0)$, $(1,-1)$, where the first and the latter are clearly not on the line $y=x$.

Comment: I see, cheers, that example clearly shows that my assumption is not true

Comment: That's a nice example. (+1).

Answer (score 11):

You can prove that if $f$ is a ***strictly increasing*** function (of course it is 1-1 and so it has an inverse), then the points of intersection of $C_f$ (the graph of $f$) and $C_{f^{-1}}$ lie on the line $y=x$. Assume a point $A(x,y)$ that is an intersection point of $C_f$ and $C_{f^{-1}}$. Since $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, one of the following holds: either $x=y$, or $x>y$, or $x<y$. We will just show that the last two lead to a contradiction due to the fact that $f$ is increasing. First of all since $A\in C_f, C_{f^{-1}}$, it holds $y=f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$. Now we take cases:

- Let $x>y$. Then $x>y \Rightarrow x>f^{-1}(x)\Rightarrow f(x) > f(f^{-1}(x)) \Rightarrow y>x $ a contradiction.
- Now let $x<y$. Similarly $x<y \Rightarrow y<x$ a contradiction.

Therefore $y=x$, which means graphically that the points of intersection lie on the line $y=x$. ($f$ increasing $\Rightarrow$ (if $(x,y)\in C_f, C_{f^{-1}}$ then $y=x$)).

However the restriction that $f$ be strictly increasing is absolutely necessary since as others have mentioned it is a quite common case that the curves intersect outside $y=x$. If your problems involve increasing functions you may simply state $f(x) = f^{-1}(x) \Leftrightarrow f(x) = x$ (The converse is trivial: if $f(x)=x$, then $x = f^{-1}(x)$, so $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ and it holds for any 1-1 function) and reduce your equation. This technique is useful not only for polynomials but also for functions involving say logarithms and exponentials. Consider $f(x) = \ln(x-1) + x$. Without the above theorem you get to solve a system of equations involving transcendental functions, whereas with the theorem you just prove $f$ is increasing and then you immediately get that the sole point of intersection of $f$ with its inverse is $(2,2)$. This means that although you can't use it with $y = -x^3$ of [mkausp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/243800/mkausp), the intersection points of $y=x^3$ are bound to be on $y=x$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the other answers:

Generally, $f$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ intersect at every $x$ and $f(x)$ for which $f(f(x))=x$. Vizualize this as a pair of points mirrored on the line $f(x)=x$. Especially, they intersect at every $x$ for which $f(x)=x$, which are the points precisely on this 'mirror'.

Chappers constructed a function for which this holds for every $x$, and thus meets its inverse everywhere. It is just a line straight through the 'mirror', which stays the same when mirrored.

But it is easy to see that $f(f(x))$ does not necessarily hold at all, for example when $f(x)$ always stays greater, or always stays less than $x$, as in mkausp's examples $exp$ and $log$. They never cross the mirror and so can not contain a pair of mirrored points.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to understand this.

Comment: I would be happy to elaborate to help you.

Comment: After going through the examples, it makes sense, it was just the wording at first, but I can now see your point. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are only half right. They will always be mirrored about the straight line $ x=y$. Intersection of $x=y$ and the function ( or its inverse) supplies all the *real* solution points, only if portions of the graph lies below line $ x=y$.

Wherever x occurs rub off and put y.Wherever original  y occurs rub off and put x. That procedure gives you the inverse function mirrored about $x=y$ whether or not it cuts $x=y$ at *real* points.

For example the circle

$$ x^2+ y^2 + 5 x + 3 y + 6 = 0 $$

has roots $(-3,-1) $ in x or y by your method.

So $(-3,-3),  (-1,-1) $  are points of  intersection without further calculation.