# Find the inverse of $f(x) = 2^{\log x} + 8$ where the base of log is $10$. Also solve the equation $f(x)$ is equal to its inverse.

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am able to find the inverse as

$$f^{-1}(x)=10^{\log_2(x-8)}.$$

On writing $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$, we get a logarithmic equation that is very complicated. By hit and trial, I found one of the $x$ to be $10$.

How can we solve that logarithmic equation? Is there a better approach?

Comment: If the log is base two, write it as such $10^{\log_2 (x-8)}$.

Comment: Bear in mind that $a^{\log_b c} = b^{\log_a b\log_b c}=(b^{b\log_b c})^\log_a b} = c^{\log_2 b}$.  So $2^{\log_{10} x} = 10^{\log_2 x}$.

Comment: @fleablood It makes sense now , in the title base is 10, in the content the base is 2. No wonder it’s confusing and better spell out as suggested.

Comment: @fleablood: You missed a ```{```: $$a^{\log_bc} = b^{\log_ab\log_bc}=(b^{b\log_b c})^{\log_a b} = c^{\log_2 b}$$

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E%28%28log%28x-8%29%29%2F%28log+2%29%29%3D2%5E%7Blog+x%7D+%2B+8&assumption=%7B%22FunClash%22%2C+%22log%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Log10%22%7D) says the only solution is $10$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $f(x)=y=2^{\log x}+8,\log(y-8)=\log 2\log x,x=10^{\frac{log(y-8)}{\log 2}},\therefore g(x)=f^{-1}(x)=10^{\frac{\log (x-8)}{log 2}}$

Since $f(x),g(x)$ intercept at  $x=y$ as mentioned in the other answer[proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452098/will-inverse-functions-and-functions-always-meet-at-the-line-y-x) :

\begin{align} x^{\log 2}+8=x \end{align}

\begin{align} x^{\log 2}=x-8 \end{align}
\begin{align} \log x\log 2=\log(x-8) \end{align}
\begin{align}\frac{ \log 2}{\log 10}=\frac{\log(x-8)}{\log x} \end{align}

Now, it is easy to see $x=10$.